#  android : how to interpret user input on edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext

The following code I used to replace `.(dot)` by `,(coma)` **while user inputing value** to edit text

InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
        FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter(){

```
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                Spanned arg3, int arg4, int arg5) {
            String temp =arg0.toString();
            temp=temp.replace('.',',');

            return temp;
        }

    };

        etxt_kg.setFilters(FilterArray);
```

The above code successfully interprets user each inputs. but it replaces nothing for .(dot)

Now : input: 12.45 Output: 1245

What i want: input 12.45 output: 12,45

Any help( TIA)

EDIT:

problem was in xml.. EditText inputType="number" .

Comment: maybe it would help to try `String temp = arg0.toString().replace('.',',');` - I got the same problem once and somehow this seemed to work

Comment: try temp=temp.replace(".", ",");

Comment: @imran khan i tried this.. not working..

Comment: @vnshetty : finally split String[] srttemp=temp.split("."); String str=srttemp[0]+","+srttemp[1];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced same scenario.Here is a solution

Use following Snippet

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (source.charAt(i) == '.') {
                return ",";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};

EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rg);
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {filter});
```

**Below is my working snippet**

```
package org.vipul;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AbcActivity extends Activity {
    EditText text;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        EditText etxt_kg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rg);
        etxt_kg.setMaxHeight(etxt_kg.getHeight());
        InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                    if (source.charAt(i) == '.') {
                        return ",";
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

        // EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rg);
        etxt_kg.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
            filter
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: working at my end! did you used same code as mine ?can you show the code

Comment: @vnshetty i have updated answer with program that is working at my end.

Comment: @i tried to run your code in HCL mE and Samsungalaxy mini tablet .. but it is not working ... if i press dot no character is entering to edit text...What is the problem?

Comment: android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

Comment: hey you are pointing it right i removed input type and it works.. but want user to enter only decimal value ..waht to do?

Comment: @vnshetty Lolz if you set it numberdecimal then you will never get comma there.Because only number and dot are supported.If you want comma there remove InputType attribute :P